# Golang - How to get all the value of checkbox? r.FormValue is not working?

Tags: checkbox, go

This is my HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="2" />
```

If I check all the options and I use `r.FormValue("product_image_id")` to get the value of checked options, I will only get the value `0`.

I mean I can only get the first value, and I can't get other value although it was checked.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[`Request.FormValue`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) only returns the first value if there is more than one. From the Documentation:

> FormValue returns the first value for the named component of the query.
>
> ...
>
> To access multiple values of the same key, call `ParseForm` and then
>   inspect `Request.Form` directly.

Answer (score 5):

`r.FormValue` returns the first value from the list of options
instead use `r.Form` , this returns a list.
you can access your values by
`r.Form["product_image_id"]`

Comment: Remember using `r.Parseform()` before using `r.Form`, otherwise it will be empty.

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
    <form method="post" name="myform" action="http://localhost:8081/post" >
     <input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="Apple" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="Orange" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="Grape" />
     <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Go

```
// ProcessCheckboxes will process checkboxes
func ProcessCheckboxes(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", r.Form)
    productsSelected := r.Form["product_image_id"]
    log.Println(contains(productsSelected, "Grape"))
}

func contains(slice []string, item string) bool {
    set := make(map[string]struct{}, len(slice))
    for _, s := range slice {
        set[s] = struct{}{}
    }
    _, ok := set[item]
    return ok
}
```

Output

Orange and Grape checboxes are checked and submitted

```
map[product_image_id:[Orange Grape]]
2016/10/27 16:16:06 true
```

Apple and Orange checboxes are checked and submitted

```
map[product_image_id:[Apple Orange]]
2016/10/27 16:17:21 false
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="product_image_id" value="4" checked/>
```

GO

```
r.Form["product_image_id"][0] == "1"
r.Form["product_image_id"][1] == "2"
r.Form["product_image_id"][2] == "4"
```

It will be working.
Am I late?